# C# - WHOIS server closing the connection early or not sending the whole response to my socket?

Tags: c#, sockets, whois

I'm sending the server `172.217.2.142\r\n` and it's only responding with:

> #
>    # ARIN WHOIS data and services are subject to the Terms of Use
>    # available at: https://www.arin.net/whois_tou.html
>    #
>    # If you see inaccuracies in the results, please report at
>    # https://www.arin.net/public/whoisinaccuracy/index.xhtml
>    #

My receive function:

```
private string getResponse(Socket sock)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    string result = string.Empty;
    int bytesReceived = 0;

    do
    {
        bytesReceived = sock.Receive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
        Debug.Print("Bytes read:" + bytesReceived.ToString());
        result += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
        Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    } while (bytesReceived > 0);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity why are you using such a low level object like `Socket` and not a higher layer abstraction like `TcpClient` or use `WebClient` with the newer Whois-RWS API?

Comment: No specific reason, just a learning experience.

Answer (score 1):

One popular way is to use WebClient to load data from the URL:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    string value = client.DownloadString("url");            
}
```

The value returned is in JSON format for arin.net.

Comment: *must* is a too strong a word and restricting in this context. Simply say "One popular way is to use" .. `Webclient`

Comment: thank you for the correction, for the poor french that I am :)